# What is the significance of the Paris back story?

Tags: plot-explanation, goddess-of-love

In the film "[Goddess of Love](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3432552/)"...

> ...the psychiatrist reads a transcript of an incident where Venus
>  ruined a dancer's career by pushing him down a staircase and caused
>  him to become paralyzed.

It appears to be unrelated to the plot and yet is poised to have major significance to Venus' current circumstances.  Was it simply a previous episode of psychotic behaviour? Or did the guilt arising from the incident induce her into schizophrenia? Or what?

> Note: Venus suffers from profound schizophrenia and some of the plot appear
>  to be visual, audio, and *strikingly* tactile hallucinations (i.e., erotic) which are presented as real events.  We already know she's irrecoverably insane, so how does the exposure of this earlier incident further inform the viewer?

Note: at the time of this question (Feb '16) there is (apparently) no wiki article on this fascinating film to assist the viewer in resolving some of the twists and turns of the plot.